# как получить значения service, где значение replicas равно 2?

Tags: python, json

как получить значения service, где значение replicas равно 2?

```
[
  {
    "replicas": 1,
    "version": "8.0.0",
    "env": "aw4",
    "service": "cat-prev-v2",
    "jobname": "cat/AppManage.8"
  },
  {
    "replicas": 2,
    "version": "2.0.8",
    "env": "aw3",
    "service": "cat-prev-v2",
    "jobname": "cat/AppManage.2"
  }
]
```

Пытался

```
import json
path = '/Users/isamarskii/Downloads/json/small.json'

with open(path, 'r') as json_data:
    parsed_data = json.load((json_data))
    #print(parsed_data)
    for i in parsed_data:
        if parsed_data['replicas'] == 2:
            print(parsed_data['service'])
```

Но получал ошибку 
**TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

Comment: `[d['service'] for d in data if d['replicas'] == 2]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Правильный варинт

```
import json

path = '/Users/isamarskii/Downloads/json/small.json'

with open(path, 'r') as json_data:
    parsed_data = json.load((json_data))
    #print(parsed_data)
    for i in parsed_data:
        if i['replicas'] == 1:
            print(i['service'])
```